Custom type for mongoengine field
I create DDD project in python and domain entities are mapped 1-1 to mongodb models.
I have the following class
class Experiment(Document, Entity):
    id: ExperimentId = ExperimentId.Field(db_field='_id', primary_key=True, required=True)
    name: ExperimentName = ExperimentName.Field(required=True)
    created_at: datetime.datetime = DateTimeField()

    def __init__(self, id: ExperimentId, name: ExperimentName):
        if not id:
            raise NoLabsException('Experiment id is empty', ErrorCodes.invalid_experiment_id)

        if not name:
            raise NoLabsException('Experiment name is empty', ErrorCodes.invalid_experiment_name)

        created_at = datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc)

        super().__init__(id=id, name=name, created_at=created_at)

    def set_name(self, name: ExperimentName):
        if not name:
            raise NoLabsException('Name cannot be empty', ErrorCodes.invalid_experiment_name)

        self.name = name

As you see id, name have theirs own field types (ExperimentId.Field is just inherited from UUIDField for example). But when I set up Experiment model id and name become UUID and str when I do experiment.name for example, not actual ExperimentId and ExperimentName that I set up before. How can I support actual types?
